# get strings from generic object in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this function that returns 2 strings

```
public object GetNamePhoneByUserId(int userId)
  {
      return _db.ApplicationUsers.Where(q => q.UserId == userId).Select(a => new { 
                a.FullName,a.PhoneNumber}).ToList();
  }
```

When calling the function, i'm getting the values, but unable to extract them from the returned value(appU)

```
object appU = _unitOfWork.ApplicationUser.GetNamePhoneByUserId(ca.UserId);
```

i was able to cast it to Ienumerable but still can't extract the values..

```
IEnumerable list = (IEnumerable)appU;
```

I'm sure its a simple solution, but tried many things and still not working.
Thank you

Comment: consider returning a value tuple or another data type. anonymous types are only good in a linq chain and not outside of the methods they are used.

Comment: Looks like this is a public method. Use a well-defined type and return that using `List<T>`. That would be best practice and give you type safety and all the benefits of using well defined types. `public List<UserModel> GetNamePhoneByUserId(){ ...`

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220126/122683

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't say that your method returns an `object`. You're going to have a really tough time working with the data, as you've seen.

Instead, create a class to represent the fields you're returning, and return a collection of that class.

```
public class ApplicationUserMinimalInfo // make this more descriptive as needed
{
    public string FullName { get; set;}
    public string PhoneNumber {get; set;}
}
```

```
public List<ApplicationUserMinimalInfo> GetNamePhoneByUserId(int userId)
{
    return _db.ApplicationUsers
        .Where(q => q.UserId == userId)
        .Select(a => new ApplicationUserMinimalInfo
        { 
            a.FullName,
            a.PhoneNumber
        }).ToList();
}
```

Now, I also suspect that because you're filtering by the UserId, you should only be getting a *single* result back, or no results back. It doesn't make sense to get two records with the same UserId.

```
public ApplicationUserMinimalInfo? GetNamePhoneByUserId(int userId)
{
    var user = _db.ApplicationUsers
        .SingleOrDefault(q => q.UserId == userId); // uses "Where" logic

    if (user is null)
        return null;
    else
        return new ApplicationUserMinimalInfo
        { 
            user.FullName,
            user.PhoneNumber
        });
}
```

---

Now, unless you *really* have some super pressing reason to have a method that returns a subset of properties, just return the full object.

```
public ApplicationUser? GetUserById(int userId)
{
    return _db.ApplicationUsers
        .SingleOrDefault(q => q.UserId == userId);
}
```

Or better yet, this method is a single line, it doesn't really need to be its own method.